# Importing edges to networkx library in Python

Tags: python, networkx, sna

I am working on a social network analysis problem where I have a directed graph. I get an issue when I import the edges to my graph file, which for some reason makes it undirected, making it impossible to measure centralities such as in/out degree etc.

## importing edge and node pandas dataframe

```
edges = pd.read_csv("./edges.csv", sep = ";")
nodes = pd.read_csv("./nodes_coordinates.csv", sep = ";")
```

## setting up the directed graph

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
nx.is_directed(G)
```

output: true

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, "from", "to")
nx.is_directed(G)
```

output: false

If that matters, here is also how I plotted the nodes, but that worked and it is still directed if I only did this part:

```
data = nodes.set_index("node").to_dict("index").items()
G.add_nodes_from(data)
nx.is_directed(G)
```

output: true

Everything works perfectly fine plotting the graph etc, but it is no longer directed, and I don't know why. Thank you for your help!

[edge csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEoop.png)

[node file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvg3B.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add parts of the csv files as plain text instead of images. In the current form they aren't really useful.

Comment: When you do `G = ....`, you're assigning whatever the right hand side is to the name `G`.  It doesn't matter what you've defined `G` to be before.  The previous value is thrown out and replaced with the new value.  For example, if I have `a=5` and then later I have `a=3`, the value of `a` is now `3`.  Doesn't matter that it was `5` earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify in the [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html) the `create_using` parameter. So replace

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, "from", "to")
```

with

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, "from", "to", create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

This gives you a new `DiGraph` instance, which means you do not need the following lines

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
nx.is_directed(G)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html), you can add a `create_using` keyword:

> **create_using** (NetworkX graph constructor, optional (default=nx.Graph)) – Graph type to create. If graph instance, then cleared before populated.

Which by default is indeed using the undirected `nx.Graph`.

Your solution would be:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, "from", "to", create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```